# Why can't the type of take be changed to use any Integral?

Tags: haskell

```
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
genericTake :: Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]
```

I have read that the inconvenient type of `take` is due to historical reasons, and that changing it could cause some code to break.

But can't I replace `take` with `genericTake` everywhere without breaking anything? What's the problem?

Comment: I guess there could be a situation where type deriving is based on `take` type -- with `genericTake` something of "cannot derive" kind will occur.

Comment: Note that in addition to (and perhaps more practically relevant than) code breakage in obscure cases, replacing `take` with `genericTake` would lead to performance degradation in a lot of cases (since type defaulting will now lead to `Integer` being used when not specifying `:: Int`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A breaking case

```
genericTake :: Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]
genericTake n xs = take (fromIntegral n) xs

class Foo a where
   bar :: a -> String

instance Foo Int where
   bar _ = "int" 

foo :: String -> [a] -> [a]
foo ns xs = let y = read ns
                z = bar y
            in take y xs
```

This will break for `genericTake`.

```
No instance for (Foo i0) arising from a use of `bar'
    The type variable `i0' is ambiguous
```

This is a cooked up example but you can understand some type inference occuring on the first argument of take where it is assumed that it is `Int`, now when you change type to `Integral i => i` some problems might occur as above.

Comment: +1 This is a real pain with type instances, and I wish it were fixed.

Comment: @jpaugh What do you suggest is a fix? I am not sure if it can be fixed.

Comment: Have not tried this, but wouldn't this compile with the extended defaulting rules?

Comment: @PhilipJF It is about what code will break without changing anything. So if such a code exists in an existing library changing type of take will break that code. Ofcourse you can do lot of things to fix that.

Comment: @PhilipJF The extended type defaulting rules won't change anything in this case. The standard defaulting rules already apply here, but since the relevant default is `Integer`, not `Int`, they simply do not help here. The extended rules only introduce defaults for more cases - they won't cause `Int` to be chosen as a default here.